# MYSQL fetched value print automatically

Tags: php

I am having problem regarding this code. How can I print the value I am fetching? It's not showing anything.

```
<?php

$comm = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("abhijit", $comm);
$new=$_POST['comment'];
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment(post) VALUES('$new')");
$str="SELECT * FROM comment";
$rom=mysql_fetch_array($str);
echo $rom['post'];

mysql_close($comm);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$str` is not a query result. For example:

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM comment";
$result = mysql_query($str);
$rom = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

However, I advise against using mysql_* functions. Learn MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: please tell me how to run this code correctly... and please tell me how to get the query result

Comment: What? It's in my answer...

Comment: yeah i got it. thanks :)...actualy i m a new learner so couldnt get that first time.

Comment: Please mark as answer if this answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

With "SELECT * FROM comment" you get the hole content of the "comment"-Table and not just the value you are fetching.
If you want to get only the value you are fetching, you have to add a WHERE-clause.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM comment WHERE post_name = ?
```

I hope I answered your question right.

Comment: I tried it i have written select post from comment but still the value is not getting printed

Comment: I don't understand why you need to read the one comment from the database. I mean the hole data of the comment is in the $_POST['comment'].

Comment: I am just trying to print it for learning. I was just experimenting. :)

Answer (score 0):

ok :) I write you this code and i hope it works, because i didn't tested it.
I just want to notice, that this code don't make any sense and it is just for learning.

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("abhijit", $comm);
// Inserting
$new = $_POST['comment'];
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment(post) VALUES('$new')");
// Reading
$str = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE post = '$new'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($str);
echo $row['post'];

mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: just one thing ur code is running successfully. IF I write "select post from comment" not fetching the value instead of ur code "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE post = '$new'"